# Creating backwards compatible p-code for teaching purposes

Tags: matlab, backwards-compatibility

I am teaching some matlab classes and we have some version-ing issues ... some students use versions as old as 2008b and some of the computers in the lab have versions as old as 2007a (or as new as 2012b). I want to create some pcode files which will run on all of these versions ... that way they can check their results without seeing the actual code that created them.

I know that Matlab 2013a (the version I use daily) can operate pcode files made from any previous version but the older versions can't run pcode made with my computer.

Is there any way to create backwards compatible pcode files? I know I can just find the oldest version and make a pcode on that computer and distribute it ... but that's really annoying. Especially because I don't have licences for versions that are as old as some of the students (my oldest is 2010a and some students/lab-computers are still stuck on 2008b)

Thanks,

Will

Comment: I am not aware of any other method than testing the code on an older version of Matlab.

Comment: Is the M-file that you're turning into P-code even backwards compatible?

Comment: Setting up a server for students to log into is another option. But a university should be doing better than running 5+ year-old versions of Matlab. You should consider discussing this with your department chair.

Comment: @horchler: Yes. The code itself is probably backwards compatible as far back as pre-2000 versions. It only uses basic linear algebra functions. As far as getting updated versions ... I've complained since 2008 when they failed to update versions but that has only fallen on deaf-ears. I've been making a push for open-source alternatives (mostly python) but that's ignored even more; ironically because the University spends so much on Matlab licences and they feel they need to use them.

Comment: I have not tried it myself, but if distributing your program in pcode won't work, perhaps creating an EXE can be a solution? (Of course you can also just encourage students to use their laptop on which they can manage updates themselves)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The pcode algorithm was redesigned in MATLAB 7.5 (Release R2007b). You can run older P-files in any current version of MATLAB; however, upcoming releases will not run P-files created before version 7.5. Files generated in 7.5, or later versions, cannot run in MATLAB 7.4 or earlier.

(Use `docsearch pcode` to view, expand "More about, Tips").

Based on the lack of any related tips or help, I suspect that pcode cannot be transitioned either way between pre-2007a and post-2007b.

From my experience, I have never had problems using pcode between versions.  I think that this algorithm change in release 7.5 is a relatively rare thing.

Comment: Yes, if I make a p-code on 2008a it will work on even the most recent version. However, a p-code made in 2013a won't run even on 2012b.

Comment: I'm running 2012b right now, so I can't even look into 2013a specific issues.  Sorry.

Comment: Its not really a specific issue to 2013a ... Its the same if you make a 2012b p-code and try to run it on 2012a.

Comment: FWIW, I just pcoded a simple function in `2012b` and was able to execute it in `2012a`.

Comment: Intriguing ... How old does it work? I've lost my ability to test back past 2013 due to liscence server issues.